# Reference a column value from a temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In a stored procedure I get a record from a table and insert it into a temporary table #temp.

Then in this stored procedure I would like to set a value in a column of the #temp table as follows:

```
declare @VarName varchar(max)
set @VarName = 'Value is ' + #temp.colname
```

There is an error on the last line.   Of course I can get the value of #temp.varname into another variable, before setting @VarName.  But I would like to know if it is possible to do it inline, without another variable name.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh  I am using SQL Server

Comment: What does `set a value in a column of the #temp table` mean? Also what do you expect to be in the variable if the temp table has more than one row?

Comment: @AaronBertrand  First, the table #temp has only one row.  
I want to the value in the variable Varname to 
'Value is  ABC'  (if the value in the column #temp.colname is 'ABC'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you mean, but it's pretty brittle in that it assumes you will only ever have one row in #temp.

```
DECLARE @VarName varchar(max) = (SELECT 'Value is ' + colname FROM #temp);
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=70c6a105697a1b4078ebd6f0d002612d)

Comment: I will try your suggestion.  On the surface it should work and looks good.  Thank you!